# Uncaught Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: web3js, events, abi

I'm listening to events of my deployed contract. Whenever a transaction gets completed and event is fired receiving the response causes following error:

> Uncaught Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
>       at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters
>   (index.js:227)
>       at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js.ABICoder.decodeLog
>   (index.js:277)

Web3 version: 1.0.0-beta36

Metamask version: 4.16.0

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in web3js, discussed [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1916#issuecomment-427398031).

And the following change fixes it ([source](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1916#issuecomment-427398031)):

```
patch-package
--- a/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js
@@ -280,7 +280,7 @@ ABICoder.prototype.decodeLog = function (inputs, data, topics) {


     var nonIndexedData = data;
-    var notIndexedParams = (nonIndexedData) ? this.decodeParameters(notIndexedInputs, nonIndexedData) : [];
+    var notIndexedParams = (nonIndexedData && nonIndexedData !== '0x') ? this.decodeParameters(notIndexedInputs, nonIndexedData) : [];

     var returnValue = new Result();
     returnValue.__length__ = 0;
```

Edit: Downgrading to 1.0.0-beta33 fixes the problem as well.

Comment: updating to latest (v1.2.9) also fixes for me